# Stacked barplot with colors depending on numbers and length of a vector

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df <- data.frame("V1" = c(0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2),
                 "V2" = c(9,9,9,0,0,2,2,2,0,0))
```

I would like to create a stacked barplot in this fashion:
[image]

So basically I map a certain value to a corresponding color (9 -> white (**invisible**), 0 -> green 2 -> red), and then create a bar of a length that is equal to the number of appearances of the value in a dataframe column. Is there any way to do something like this, i.e. using ggplot2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your dataframe to a long format using `pivot_longer`. Add a column with the colors you want to show the bars using `case_when` for example. You could use `scale_fill_identity` to fill the bars to the corresponding color. To get the same order fill in your stacked bars as your dataframe, you could use `ggplot_build` to modify the data of your plot by replace the column of "fill" with a vector of the same order as your dataframe. You can use the following code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
# Create plot
p <- df %>%
  mutate(index = 1) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -index) %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(value == 9 ~ 'white',
                           value == 0 ~ 'darkgreen',
                           TRUE ~ 'red')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = index, y = name, fill = color)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = pretty_breaks(2)) +
  labs(x = '', y = '')

# Extract vector of colors in right order
vec_colors <- df %>%
  mutate(index = 1) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -index) %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(value == 9 ~ 'white',
                           value == 0 ~ 'darkgreen',
                           TRUE ~ 'red')) %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  pull(color)

# right order colors
vec_colors
#>  [1] "darkgreen" "darkgreen" "darkgreen" "darkgreen" "darkgreen" "red"      
#>  [7] "red"       "red"       "red"       "red"       "white"     "white"    
#> [13] "white"     "darkgreen" "darkgreen" "red"       "red"       "red"      
#> [19] "darkgreen" "darkgreen"

# use ggplot_build to modify data and replace fill column with vector
q <- ggplot_build(p)
q$data[[1]] <- q$data[[1]] %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  arrange(x, .by_group = TRUE) 

q$data[[1]]$fill <- vec_colors

q <- ggplot_gtable(q)

# plot 
plot(q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

To add the legend, you should specify `guide = 'legend'` in `scale_fill_identity`. To determine which elements you want to show in the legend, you should specify the `labels` and `breaks` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
# Create plot
p <- df %>%
  mutate(index = 1) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -index) %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(value == 9 ~ 'white',
                           value == 0 ~ 'darkgreen',
                           TRUE ~ 'red')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = index, y = name, fill = color)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = 'legend',
                      labels = c('darkgreen', 'red'),
                      breaks = c('darkgreen', 'red')) +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = pretty_breaks(2)) +
  labs(x = '', y = '')

# Extract vector of colors in right order
vec_colors <- df %>%
  mutate(index = 1) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -index) %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(value == 9 ~ 'white',
                           value == 0 ~ 'darkgreen',
                           TRUE ~ 'red')) %>%
  arrange(name) %>%
  pull(color)

# use ggplot_build to modify data and replace fill column with vector
q <- ggplot_build(p)
q$data[[1]] <- q$data[[1]] %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  arrange(x, .by_group = TRUE) 

q$data[[1]]$fill <- vec_colors

q <- ggplot_gtable(q)

# plot 
plot(q)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately, if you take a closer look, our plots differ when it comes to V2.

Comment: @thesecond, Aah I see. I will update my answer soon!

Comment: @thesecond, Updated my answer! You could use `ggplot_build` to modify the data in your plot.

Comment: masterpiece! thank you!

Comment: I'm really sorry to bother you, but do you know why the legend doesn't appear?

Comment: Hi @thesecond, You should add `guide = 'legend'` in `scale_fill_identity` to add the legend.

Comment: thanks, I see! However I'm struggling a bit to properly map colors to legend labels. I tried `scale_fill_identity(guide = 'legend', labels = unique(df$V1)`, but the colors in the legend are swapped relative to those on the chart and I can't really get rid of the legend's part for value 9 (color white)

Comment: @thesecond, So if I understand you correctly, you only want to show the green and red part in your legend?

Comment: Yes, I've also extended your approach to more than only two values, by doing `mutate(color = case_when(value == 9 ~ 'white',
value == 0 ~ 'darkgreen',
value == 1 ~ 'blue',
value == 2 ~ 'red',
value == 3 ~ 'darkorange')`.
I'd like to show only values 0,1,2,3  in my legend.

Comment: @thesecond, check my edited answer! You should specify the `labels` and `breaks` in `scale_fill_identity`.

Comment: thanks! It's not my desired output, as I'd like to have numerical values for corresponding colours, so kind of an inverse transform. I.e. green colour -> "State 0", red colour -> "State 2"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way. The complicated part is to get different values from the data given the groups they belong to.

```r
df <- data.frame("V1" = c(0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2),
                 "V2" = c(9,9,9,0,0,2,2,2,0,0))

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(ggplot2)
})

df %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(V1 = cur_group_id()) %>%
  group_by(V1, V2) %>%
  mutate(V2 = cur_group_id()) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(width = 0.75) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(`1` = "darkolivegreen", `2` = "red", 
               `3` = "darkolivegreen", `4` = "white")
  ) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using `rle` we may account for duplicated values in columns V2, then use a `factor` with specific `level=` order. Then just `barplot` the column `table`s.

```
cvec <- c(0, 'darkgreen', 'red', 'darkgreen')
par(lty=0)  ## to omit borders
lapply(rev(df), \(x) factor(with(rle(x), rep.int(seq_along(values), lengths)), levels=c(3:1, 4))) |>
   sapply(table) |> barplot(width=.5, space=1, col=cvec, horiz=TRUE, ylim=c(-1, 3))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), V2 = c(9, 
9, 9, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```